# Negative Zero in Rust Pattern Matching

Tags: pattern-matching, rust

I'm reading the [Rust tutorial](http://doc.rust-lang.org/master/tutorial.html) on rust-lang.org, and I came across the following code:

```
use std::f64;
fn angle(vector: (f64, f64)) -> f64 {
    let pi = f64::consts::PI;
    match vector {
      (0.0, y) if y < 0.0 => 1.5 * pi,
      (0.0, _) => 0.5 * pi,
      (x, y) => (y / x).atan()
    }
}
```

Normally for `atan2` I would expect to see special cases for `-0` and `0`, for example to implement cases like these:

```
atan2(+0, +0) = +0
atan2(+0, −0) = +π
atan2(−0, +0) = −0
atan2(−0, −0) = −π
```

I'm not saying the tutorial should include those examples. After all it's just a demonstration of the `match` structure.

I'm just wondering if `0.0` would match `-0.0` as well? Or if the two would be recognized as disjoint values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can just try and test it! Here is a link to playtest: http://is.gd/NiS0gF

Apparently, `0.0` matches `-0.0`. This code:

```
fn main() {
    let x = -0.0f64;
    match x {
        0.0f64 => println!("Zero!"),
        _ => println!("Something else!")
    }
}
```

when run on playtest prints "Zero!", so `0.0` and `-0.0` are the same thing from `match` perspective. And this is quite natural, provided that

```
fn main() {
    println!("{}", -0.0f64 == 0.0f64);
}
```

[also prints "true"](http://is.gd/q6vyFJ).

Comment: That makes sense, these kinds of comparisons are better done using specialized floating point functions.